# Show private pages in public when you logged in as admin?

Tags: admin, pages, private

Is there any way to show private pages at the public website section when you logged in as admin? Today, they only shows in admin.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `query_posts` parameter where you normally use `published`, but can use `private` too.

Comment: Discovered a problem. It's visible even when i'm offline.

Comment: You could wrap it with a `if ( current_user_can( '*some capability*' ) ) : /* do stuff */ endif;`